# FontMetrics.getStringBounds for AttributedString gives wrong result?

Tags: java, swing, awt

As shown in the following picture, an AttributedString is drawn on a JPanel (500X500).

The `FontMetrics.getStringBounds()` of that AttributedString gives a width of 164.0, as indicated by the trace output.

```
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-12.064453,w=164.0,h=15.09375]
```

However, the picture suggests the width should be 300-400 (because the width of the panel is 500).

Could you help to comment the reason and the workaround ?

[image]

#### MyJFrame.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.text.AttributedString;

class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
    MyJPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gold) {
        super.paintComponent(gold);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gold;
        //
        AttributedString text = new AttributedString("Bunny rabits and flying ponies");
        text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24), 0, "Bunny rabits".length());
        text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.RED, 0, "Bunny rabits".length());

        text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD & Font.ITALIC, 32), 17, 17 + "flying ponies".length());
        text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 17, 17 + "flying ponies".length());

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

        System.out.println(fm.getStringBounds(text.getIterator(), 0, text.getIterator().getEndIndex(), g));
        g.drawString(text.getIterator(), 50, 50);
        //
        g.dispose();
    }
}

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyJFrame frame = new MyJFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new MyJPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics()` returns a `FontMetrics` object based on the single font currently set on the `graphics` object. You are not changing the font used by `graphics` explicitly so it uses the default font designated for `JPanel` by the current L&F.

`FontMetrics` methods related to bounds calculation accept a "simple" `CharacterIterator` (which does not provide font information) instead of `AttributedCharacterIterator` (which does). Hence `fontMetrics.getStringBounds()` simply calculates the text bounds based on the single font of the same size.

You need to use `java.awt.font.TextLayout` to determine the proper bounds when using `AttributedCharacterIterator` with different fonts and font sizes:

```
TextLayout textLayout = new TextLayout( 
        text.getIterator(), 
        g.getFontRenderContext() 
);
Rectangle2D.Float textBounds = ( Rectangle2D.Float ) textLayout.getBounds();

g.drawString( text.getIterator(), 50, 50 );
// lets draw a bounding rect exactly around our text
// to be sure we calculated it properly
g.draw( new Rectangle2D.Float(
        50 + textBounds.x, 50 + textBounds.y,
        textBounds.width, textBounds.height
) );
```

Comment: When using `Rectangle2D` instead of `Rectangle2D.Float`, you can avoid the cast. However, `TextLayout` seems to be another option (besides `TextMeasurer`, as in my answer) - so +1 anyhow

Comment: @Marco13 plain `Rectangle2D` API is `double`-based. Either you cast to `Rectangle2D.Float` and use simple `float` fields or you do not cast the object but will have to use `getSomething():double` getters and cast from `double` to `float` everywhere else.

Comment: You don't know whether `getBounds` returns a `Rectangle` or a `Rectangle2D.Float` or a `Rectangle2D.Double`. Casting there may throw a `ClassCastException`, because the type of the `Rectangle` is simply not specified. You can rely on the `Rectangle2D` API, which is using `double` for all getters. In order to draw the rectangle, you can create a `new Rectangle2D.Double(50 + textBounds.getX(), ...)`.

Comment: I know because its source code is available. It was always R2D.Float and probably always will be.

Comment: I think this is just a matter of "good practice" and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface , but here it can be considered as a detail that is not directly related to the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

The `FontMetrics` only receives a `CharacterIterator`, and does not take into account that it is actually an `AttributedCharacterIterator`. You can use a `TextMeasurer` to compute the actual bounds of your string. For comparison, add this after you called the `drawString` method:

```
    // Compensate for the 50,50 of the drawString position
    g.translate(50, 50);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    Rectangle2D wrongBounds = fm.getStringBounds(
            text.getIterator(), 0, text.getIterator().getEndIndex(), g);
    g.draw(wrongBounds);
    System.out.println("wrong: "+wrongBounds);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    AttributedCharacterIterator iterator = text.getIterator();
    TextMeasurer tm = new TextMeasurer(iterator, g.getFontRenderContext());
    Rectangle2D rightBounds = tm.getLayout(0, iterator.getEndIndex()).getBounds();
    g.draw(rightBounds);
    System.out.println("right: "+rightBounds);
```

(And BTW: Don't call `g.dispose()` on the `Graphics` that was handed to you in the `paintComponent` method)