# Java AttributedString, both bold and superscript

Tags: java, swing, text, rendering

I am trying to render a `java.text.AttributedString` which is both bold and superscript. While it works to make some range either bold or superscripted, the rendering can't seem to handle a range that is both bold and superscript.

The following SSCCE shows that rendering this using a JLabel with HTML text works fine. Is there a way to get this behaviour without a JLabel?

Btw, I had a look into the created AttributedString properties and they look okay by me, so it is definitively a rendering problem.

```
package funky.chart;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class AttributedStringTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prevent using the default UI manager who renders in bold by default for the HTML label
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Could not set look and feel: " + ex);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AttributedString superscript with font");

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics gfx) {
                super.paint(gfx);

                Font bold = gfx.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD);

                // superscript and bold only works fine
                AttributedString test1 = new AttributedString("test superscript and bold");
                test1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 5, 16);
                test1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, bold, 21, 25);

                // both superscript and bold is only rendered as bold
                AttributedString test2 = new AttributedString("test superscript and bold");
                test2.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 5, 25);
                test2.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, bold, 5, 25);

                gfx.drawString(test1.getIterator(), 5, 20);
                gfx.drawString(test2.getIterator(), 5, 40);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 70);
            }
        });

        // HTML label works fine
        frame.getContentPane().add(
                new JLabel("<html>test <b>bold</b>, <sup>super</sup> and <b><sup>both</sup></b>"),
                BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes on your complete example:

- Use [`TextAttribute.WEIGHT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) to specify **bold**.
- Use [`TextAttribute.SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) to specify font size.
- Use [`TextLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html) to calculate the preferred size, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24019384/230513).
- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360762/230513 */
public class AttributedStringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new AttributedStringTest()::display);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AttributedString superscript with font");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                // superscript and bold only works fine
                AttributedString test1 = new AttributedString("test superscript and bold");
                test1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 28, 0, 25);
                test1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 5, 16);
                test1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD, 21, 25);

                // both superscript and bold is only rendered as bold
                AttributedString test2 = new AttributedString("test superscript and bold");
                test2.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 28, 0, 25);
                test2.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 5, 25);
                test2.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD, 5, 25);

                g.drawString(test1.getIterator(), 5, 35);
                g.drawString(test2.getIterator(), 5, 70);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 80);
            }
        });

        // HTML label works fine
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(
            "<html>test <b>bold</b>, <sup>super</sup> and <b><sup>both</sup></b>", JLabel .CENTER),
            BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, trashgod... I overlooked the `WEIGHT` attribute. You're also right about the general Swing guidelines you mentioned, of course. But what's that `new AttributedStringTest()::display` syntax -- looks like C++ to me, or is it some functional Java 8 stuff?

Comment: @FranzD.: Exactly; see [*Method References*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: I like that... Thanks for enlightening me in more than one ways :)