# add subscripts and a font to a String in graphics on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fonts, subscript

I want to Draw a string on my JFrame that has subscripts and a font, I was trying to use an AttributedString but i didn't seem to want to work for whatever reason. It will either display just the font or just the subscripts but not both at once.

```
private class DrawFormulas extends JComponent
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        Graphics2D G2D = (Graphics2D)g;

        G2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setFont(F);

        AttributedString Trig = new AttributedString("a2 + b2 = c2");
        Trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, F);
        Trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 1, 2);
        Trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 6, 7);
        Trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 11, 12);
        Trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, F.getSize());
        G2D.drawString(Trig.getIterator(), 170, 75);

    }
}
```

If somebody can tell me why this doesn't work or has a better way of doing this any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Which is your font?

Comment: It's F which is defined outside of the method                                                                                  
Font F = new Font("SANS_SERIF", Font.PLAIN, 60);

Comment: 1+ for a nice snippet, however be sure that next time you post a valid [mcve] so we don't need to ask what the font (or whatever data inside your code) is. My answer shows an example of that MCVE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why when using both `TextAttribute.FONT` and `TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT` doesn't merge those attributes, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360762/2180785) by @thrashgod gave the idea with your solution.

Separate the `Font` object into:

- Font size = 60
- Font family = `Font.SANS_SERIF`
- Font style = `Font.PLAIN`

As the style is plain we only need font size and font family, so I ended with something like this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.text.AttributedString;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FormulaDrawer {
    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FormulaDrawer()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        Drawer drawer = new Drawer();

        frame.add(drawer);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class Drawer extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            AttributedString trig = new AttributedString("a2 + b2 = c2");
            trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FAMILY, "Comic Sans MS"); //Change to Font.SANS_SERIF constant
            trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 20);

            trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 1, 2);
            trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 6, 7);
            trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 11, 12);

            g2d.drawString(trig.getIterator(), 50, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

However you might have noticed I used a font size of 20 instead of 60, well that's because it seemed too big for me, just change it and you're done, and also I used another font, so you can see you can use any font you want (just be sure to have installed that font or export it within your JAR file)

The general idea was to use the font attributes separately as shown in the above code in these lines:

```
trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FAMILY, "Comic Sans MS");
trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 20);
```

And this is how it looks like :)

[image]

---

Also be sure to follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) so your code becomes easier to read for you and us:

- `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`
- `firstWordLowerCaseMethod(...)`
- `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`
- `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`

Another improvement to your code is: try not extending and overriding `JComponent` and `paint()` method respectively, instead extend `JPanel` or any other component and override it's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and be sure to call `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first line inside it so you don't break the paint chain.

My `main(...)` method might look strange to you too because of the [Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) in Java 8 and the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) where you should **always** start your Swing program.

---

> is there a way I can do that with the style of a font?

Yes, there is (as was shown in the link to thrashgod's answer)

- **Bold** text is with [`TextAttribute.WEIGHT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#WEIGHT)
- *Italic* text is with [`TextAttribute.POSTURE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#POSTURE)

You can find more styles reading the [`TextAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) docs

For example:

```
trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD);
trig.addAttribute(TextAttribute.POSTURE, TextAttribute.POSTURE_OBLIQUE);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked great.  One more question thou.  I was able to set size through F.getSize() and I can set the family through F.getFamily() but is there a way I can do that with the style of a font?  I'm pretty sure you set it with TextAttribute.WEIGHT but I don't know how I would pull it out of the font.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was very helpful :)

Comment: Glad it helped, don't forget to take the tips given into account.

Answer (score 0):

> If somebody can tell me why this doesn't work
>
> I'm not sure why when using both TextAttribute.FONT and
>   TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT doesn't merge those attributes

This is because the FONT TextAttribute is handled in a special way. From the javadoc:

> ... Normally, all the attributes are examined and used to select and
>   configure a Font instance. If a FONT attribute is present, though, its
>   associated Font will be used. ... Typically, there will be no other attributes in the Map except the FONT attribute.

Javadoc also explains that other attributes can be used together with the FONT attribute, but NOT the following ones:  FAMILY, WEIGHT, WIDTH, POSTURE, SIZE, TRANSFORM, SUPERSCRIPT, and TRACKING.

That's why the SUPERSCRIPT attribute was ignored.