# Superscript in java

Tags: java, superscript

I am a completely noob with Java.
I can't figure out what is the problem with my code.

Eclipse says `pythagorasComponent(TextAttribute)` is undefined for the type 
object.

Can you give me a hand please?

```
public class Pythagoras {
public void pythagorasComponent(TextAttribute two) {
    AttributedString to = new AttributedString("Your \u25b2's c2 equals 
with");
    super.pythagorasComponent(two);
    to.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, 
 TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 15, 16);

}
//I imported the following: 
//import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
//import java.lang.Math;
//import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.text.AttributedString;
```

Comment: You are calling super.pythagoras invoking the pythagoras method on your super class which is Object (as you are not extending any other class).

Why are you doing that?

Comment: what are u trying to do with super?

Comment: I'd like to supercript the number '2'

Comment: google "java super keyword"

Answer (score 0):

Your are confused as to what the `super` keyword means. Plese see [this page](https://www.javatpoint.com/super-keyword) on `super`.

To assign the superscript attribute to an `AttributedString`, you should do as illustrated in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360762/7015661).

This is mainly done by creating the `AttributedString` as you have done and assign the superscript property by using the indices such as:

```
AttributedString test = new AttributedString("test superscript and bold");
test.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 5, 25);
```

Where the 5 and 25 are the start and end indices of the *superscript* part of the `String`.