# Java, powers and indexes output in UI

Tags: java, swing

How is it possible to make an output in Java in Swing in JLabel with a string, where there are symbols with indexes and powers? For example: output of x^2 (x*x).

Comment: You try using unicodes for the characters. You could look up the font table for the font your are using to see if it has those characters. You might be able to use superscript capabilities of HTML

Answer (score 7):

Wild guess - you want to make the display *look nice*. Well then:

*Swing Components* can display (limited) **HTML**. So this actually works:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>a<sup>2</sup> * x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub>");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
```

will create a display like

[image: shown dialog]

Use

- `<sup>` for superscript or
- `<sub>` for subscript

Answer (score 5):

## You could...

Make use of `JLabel`'s HTML support and use `<sup>` (superscript), for example...

[image: Superscript]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(new JLabel("<html>2<sup>*</sup>2"), gbc);
        add(new JLabel("<html>2<sup>^</sup>2"), gbc);
    }

}
```

## You could...

Make use of the unicode support (assuming your font supports it)

[image: Unicode]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(new JLabel("2\u00B2"), gbc);
    }

}
```

Have a look at [Unicode character table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#00B2) for more suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Also consider an [`AttributedString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html) in your own `JComponent`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360762/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808858/230513).

[image]

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.add(new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        String s = "ax [m/s2]";
        AttributedString as = new AttributedString(s);
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 24, 0, 2);
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 16, 3, 9);
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD, 0, 2);
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUB, 1, 2);
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 7, 8);
        g.drawString(as.getIterator(), 12, 32);
    }
});
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: As suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23975076/230513), use `TextLayout` for bounds.